# AWS Lambda function continues for a bit after context.fail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple AWS Lambda function that does some validation on images saved to an S3 bucket. I'm using async.waterfall to download the image and process it, but before I even enter the first waterfall function, I do some basic validation on the event data that I am getting from my S3 PutObject trigger, specifically the size information (`event.Records[0].s3.object.size`). If the event references an image that is greater than my MAX_SIZE, I use `context.fail(new Error("Validation error: the file is too big."))` to end execution.

This is all working fine, but I notice in my logs that after the error is logged, the function continues to run for a little bit before it is exited. For example, the first function in my async.waterfall call gets called (i.e. a message from that function shows in the log). I even tried adding a `context.done(errorMessage)` immediately after the context.fail, and it gets executed (i.e. the message I pass in gets logged) along with a few more lines of code.

Is this expected behavior? I could not find any mention of this in the docs. Does the function take a little bit of time to exit or am I misunderstanding the synchronous nature of the code in the handler function that is BEFORE `async.waterfall`?

Below is some of my code. All the `console.log` messages that are shown after `context.fail` get printed to the log, which I wouldn't expect to happen.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  if (event.Records[0].s3.object.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
    var error = new Error("Validation error: the file is too big.")
    context.fail(error);
  }
  console.log('Event validation complete.')

  var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  var key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  var fileName = key.split("/")[1];
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key
  };
  console.log('Starting processing of the following file: ' + JSON.stringify(params, null, 2));

  async.waterfall([
    function download(callback) {
        // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
        console.log("Downloading the image from S3...");
        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                callback(null, data);
            }
        });
    },
  ...
  ], ...)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears to be expected behavior, even if not well documented.  The [context documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-methods) does say `fail()` "indicates failure" but does not promise to stop further execution.

> **context.fail()**
>
> Indicates the Lambda function execution and all callbacks completed unsuccessfully, resulting in a handled exception.

The good news for your code is that it should be fairly easy to `return` from the function after calling `context.fail()` to avoid further processing.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay!! Thanks for the help! `return` worked (for the Node.js v0.10.42 runtime), but why? Is that documented somewhere, or something I'm supposed to know about Node.js? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html

Comment: Correction, this also works in the latest supported version of Node.js (v4.3). `return` cuts the execution immediately, but I still don't understand why. It's not documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html

Comment: I expect there is a natural disconnect between the Node interpreter running your function and the Lambda infrastructure supervising the environment. I can only recommend defensive coding there.  @emispowder's answer offers some more precise control, you might want to try that out.

Comment: `context.fail()` must be an asynchronous function, meaning its pushed into the event loop and won't run until its turn.  By using `return` you end the `handler()` function  immediately and allow `context.fail()` to have its turn to run immediately.

Comment: Hi, it's now 2019 and I can't seem to find any documentation on `context.fail()` -- has it been deprecated or removed? Following the link in this answer doesn't mention `fail()` anywhere

Comment: I landed here with the same question as you @emmdee. As far as I can tell `context.fail()` doesn't exist any more, although I cannot find any information that explicitly states this.

Comment: It seems that the docs dropped all mention of `context.succeed()`, `context.fail()`, `context.done()` sometime around 2015 – 2016, but here is an entry from 2015 which still has it: https://web.archive.org/web/20151014113651/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

Answer (score 14):

I believe the aws lambda structure has changed a bit since this question was asked (and James' answer).

Now the handler additionally has a [third argument](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback), 'callback', which can be called to stop execution of the script. Depending how you call it, it exits the process successfully or with an error. See those docs for specifics.

Additionally, check out the context property, [callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-properties). It defaults to true, but you will want to set it to false so that, once the callback is called, the node process doesn't wait for the runtime loop to clear, i.e. your Async calls are thrown away.

Comment: Except they won't be "thrown away", they are still there even if the process gets frozen and their callbacks will run within following lambda invocations. So, be careful.

Comment: This is the best correct answer now but there is an even "newer" way, you can return a promise from your handler and promise rejection will have the same result as calling the callback. You can still use the callback too of course.